# UICollectionViewWaterfallLayout - How to setup properties and delegate

Tags: properties, delegates, ios6, uicollectionview

in the latest issue of iOS Dev Weekly there was an interesting article about the UICollectionWaterfallLayout: https://github.com/chiahsien/UICollectionViewWaterfallLayout
As you see, there are 2 steps to be performed in order to get working the sample app. But, because I'm a newbie in Objective-C and iOS development I get stuck in these steps.

In particular:

Step 1: What does it mean setup those 3 properties and 1 delegate? I know what properties and delegates are, but equally I don't know what to do.

Step 2: How can I implement that method in my delegate?

Sorry for the obvious questions. I'm studying on the Big Nerd Ranch book but I'm still in trouble with this platform.

Thanks all in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a "layout", which means you also need to provide a viewController and a collectionView by yourself, then wrap these 3 things up!

Here is an example:
In your WaterfallViewController.h

```
#import "UICollectionViewWaterfallLayout.h"
@interface WaterfallViewController : UIViewController <UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollecitonViewDelegateWaterfallLayout>
@property (nonatomic, strong) UICollectionView *collectionView;
@end
```

And in your WaterfallViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UICollectionViewWaterfallLayout *layout = [[UICollectionViewWaterfallLayout alloc] init];
    layout.delegate = self;
    layout.columnCount = 2;
    layout.itemWidth = 146;
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(9, 9, 9, 9);

    _collectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds collectionViewLayout:layout];
    _collectionView.dataSource = self;
    _collectionView.delegate = self;
    _collectionView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
    _collectionView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    [_collectionView registerClass:[MyCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MyCell"];

    [self.view addSubview:self.collectionView];
}

#pragma mark - UICollecitonViewDelegateWaterfallLayout Delegate
- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                   layout:(UICollectionViewWaterfallLayout *)collectionViewLayout
 heightForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // return the height for cell at indexPath.
}
```

Sorry for the inconvenient, I'll add some sample codes to the repo soon.

Comment: Nelson- Is there a way to add headers to your control?